# Trying to Replace storage chooser with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scoped-storage

I'm trying to replace a deprecated part of code with kotlin. I need it to let me pick a folder,  do a check to make sure it's the correct folder (a Morrowind.ini file and "Data Files" directory must be present) and then return that path to a variable game_files.

My android knowledge is extremely limited and I've been at this for weeks.

```
findPreference("game_files").setOnPreferenceClickListener {
            // Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent to allow the user to choose a directory
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            true
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        data?.data?.also { uri ->
            // Persist access permissions for the selected directory using takePersistableUriPermission
            activity.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

            // Use the selected directory URI to perform operations
            val selectedDirectory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, uri)
            val path = selectedDirectory?.uri?.path ?: ""
            setupData(path)
        }
    }
}
```

which should send the data path to

```
private fun setupData(path: String) {
    val sharedPref = preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences

    // reset the setting so that it's erased on error instead of keeping
    // possibly stale value
    var gameFiles = ""

    val inst = GameInstaller(path)
    if (inst.check()) {
        val iniFile = File(path, "Morrowind.ini")
        val dataFilesFolder = File(path, "Data Files")

        if (iniFile.exists() && dataFilesFolder.exists() && dataFilesFolder.isDirectory) {
            inst.setNomedia()
            if (!inst.convertIni(sharedPref.getString("pref_encoding", GameInstaller.DEFAULT_CHARSET_PREF)!!)) {
                showError(R.string.data_error_title, R.string.ini_error_message)
            } else {
                gameFiles = path
            }
        } else {
            // If either Morrowind.ini or Data Files folder is missing
            showError(R.string.data_error_title, R.string.data_error_message)
```

I can't get it to work though. It lets me pick a folder and I can clearly see the file and directory there but receive the error message about them missing. I hope this is a better explanation and only relevant code. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Well what is the problem? Where does it go wrong? And why did you also post a lot of irrelevant code,?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't sure whats relevant or not.  It will let me choose a directory but never detects the ini file or directory... just keeps giving me the error message that they are missing and it's definitely the correct directory

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question itself, not in comments. Also, replace your entire code snippet by a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that only contains the relevant code parts (hence the "*minimal*")

Comment: `. just keeps giving me the error message that they are missing ` We dont see those messages. But anyhow they are your own messages i suppose. You better tell what happens that you display such a message.

Comment: For using SAF ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you do not need any permission. So now please remove the code where you request that WRITE permission.

Comment: ok I removed the "ask permission" part which it doesn't seem to notice. 
still not passing the path maybe? 
I feel like this line "setupData(path)" is where its going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I changed the first part to

```
findPreference("game_files").setOnPreferenceClickListener {
            // Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent to allow the user to choose a directory
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            true
    }
```

and the second part is

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        data?.data?.also { uri ->

            val selectedDirectory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, uri) ?: return
            val iniFile = selectedDirectory.findFile("Morrowind.ini")
            val dataFilesFolder = selectedDirectory.findFile("Data Files")
            val sharedPref = preferenceScreen.sharedPreferences


            if (iniFile != null && dataFilesFolder != null && dataFilesFolder.isDirectory) {
                val gameFilesPreference = findPreference("game_files")
                val path = uri.toString() // Convert Uri to String path
                gameFilesPreference?.summary = path
                with(sharedPref.edit()) {
                    var gameFiles = path
                    putString("game_files", gameFiles)
                    apply()
                }
            } else {
                showError(R.string.data_error_title, R.string.data_error_message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Incase anyone is wondering about this

Comment: Yes that is the way to go. Using the File class was impossible here. Glad you found all this.